# Formatting number to a specific number of digits in Fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am trying to format a number to a certain number of digits (7, actually) like the following:

```
215.5745
6.569674
16.42418
```

According to [this page](https://www.l3harrisgeospatial.com/docs/format_codes_fortran.html) ("F, D, E, and G Format Codes"), the possible format code would be:

```
[n]F[+][-][w][.d]
```

> The variable w specifies the number of digits to be transferred

which appears to be exactly what I am looking for.

I understand that the d parameter should not be provided as this would cause the number of decimal positions to be fixed, and could be omitted since:

> d is an optional width specification

However, gfortran refuses to compile when a format code like "F7" is provided.

`Error: Period required in format specifier in format string at (1)`

Comment: You want a set number of digits after the decimal as stated, or a set number of _significant_ digits as shown in the example. The first requires the `fw.d` formatting and the latter the `gw.d` formatting. Also, note that `w=0` with newer compilers for a best-fit approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linked page appears to be over-simplified or straight-out incorrect. The period is indeed obligatory. The number the period must be non-negative (positive or zero).

I do not think you can do exactly what you require using these format descriptors. Instead, I would first print the number into a string and then only print the first 8 digits of that string - but it is not accurate because it just cuts the remaining digits instead of rounding them.

If you need to be precise, you will have to count the digits before the comma and set-up the format string manually. There won't be a universal format string to use as far as I am aware.

```
    double precision :: a(3) = [215.5745d0,6.569674d0,16.42418d0]
    integer :: digs(3)
    character(20) :: form

    digs = log10(a) + 1

    do i = 1, 3
        write(form,'(a,i0,a)') "(f8.", max(min(7-digs(i),7),0), ")"
        print form, a(i)
    end do

end
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand that there would be a problem if the number was 0.0000009. By taking the first 7 characters (+1 for the dot character), you would be left with 0.000000 when you should have rounded to 0.000001. This would certainly be problematic for my use case as rounding to the correct number is important.

Comment: Yes, I know, I just added that remark into my answer.

Comment: If you need to be precise, you will have to count the digits before the comma and set-up the format string manually. There won't be a universal format string to use as far as I am aware.

Comment: Your code works wonders. Thank you very much for such a creative answer. Have a nice day.

Comment: I made a short fix to allow values of the full possible range.

Answer (score 3):

I think the `g0.7` formatting spec should give you exactly what you want.

here is a small test code for formatting.

```
print '(1x,a24,1x,a24,1x,a24)', "g24.7", "e24.7", "f24.7"
do i=1, n
    print '(1x,g24.7,1x,e24.7,1x,f24.7)', a64(i), a64(i), a64(i)
end do
```

and the sample output

As you can see the `gw.7` type of format retains a certain number of significant digits which is what your example shows. But if this is not possible, then it reverts to scientific formatting.

```
                g24.7                    e24.7                    f24.7
        0.3710828E-02            0.3710828E-02                0.0037108
         8.318075                0.8318075E+01                8.3180745
         33.02631                0.3302631E+02               33.0263091
         133.7840                0.1337840E+03              133.7839844
         152.5674                0.1525674E+03              152.5673802
         274.5596                0.2745596E+03              274.5595695
         317.6714                0.3176714E+03              317.6713521
         452.4193                0.4524193E+03              452.4193376
         646.8024                0.6468024E+03              646.8024139
         1117.582                0.1117582E+04             1117.5816049
         1384.222                0.1384222E+04             1384.2222737
         5529.837                0.5529837E+04             5529.8374344
         6555.235                0.6555235E+04             6555.2346832
         24251.70                0.2425170E+05            24251.6980498
         27283.39                0.2728339E+05            27283.3873660
         167907.9                0.1679079E+06           167907.8873403
         270053.5                0.2700535E+06           270053.4615256
         317435.1                0.3174351E+06           317435.0603955
         586812.5                0.5868125E+06           586812.5125615
         3538679.                0.3538679E+07          3538679.3597321
```

Comment: In the text you say: "I think the g0.7 formatting spec should give you exactly what you want." but in the example (should be a complete MWE) you use "g24.7". Why the difference?

Comment: In the example, I needed to format with fixed-width columns, and hence I used `g24.7` for 24 character wide columns. But in general, you can use `g0.7`  to let the system decide how wide the result be in order to fit 7 significant digits.

Comment: Lifesaver! Been looking for a way to extract a set number of sig figs in Fortran for ages.  Cheers!

Comment: @SAL - See my post in the [Fortran Forum](https://fortran-lang.discourse.group/t/fortran-code-snippets/2150/33?u=jalexiou) on sample code on how to format a 2D matrix with fixed columns and a set number of significant digits.